# How to convert string to date object in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a string in this format
`String oldstring = "Mar 19 2018 - 14:39";`

How to convert this string to java object so that I get time and mins from date object.

I have tried like this,

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class DateEg {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String oldstring = "Mar 19 2018 - 14:39";
        String time = localDateFormat.format(oldstring);
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

But getting error, saying `Cannot format given Object as a Date`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:332)
    at java.base/java.text.Format.format(Format.java:158)
    at DateEg.main(DateEg.java:9)
```

Is it possible to parse this string format in java?

Comment: Your format mask is off.  The mask you specified has only hours and minutes but your timestamp has much more than this.

Comment: You question title says "convert string to date". Are you sure you want to `format` and not to `parse`?

Comment: We *format* object to text, we *parse* text to object.

Comment: I had misunderstanding between format and parse. thanks @Pshemo

Comment: @lexicore No. I want to parse the string.

Comment: @Arun Then call `parse`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User proper formatter with your code to parse string  mentioned below

```
    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm");
    String oldstring = "Mar 19 2018 - 14:39";
    Date date=localDateFormat.parse(oldstring);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: How to get only hour and mins from date object?

Comment: @Arun see my edited answer

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try using this, this should work:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parse(oldstring);`

DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
String time = timeFormat.format(dt).toString();`
```

Comment: You should probably mention that the first version uses the Joda-Time API: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/

Comment: @d.j.brown Or `java.time.format`.

Comment: I submitted an [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19304647) to get those cited, just waiting on approval

Comment: @laxicore, no, that's Joda. Equivalent `java.time.format` class is called `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @Arun, I have edited the answer, do check this out

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                   // Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because the input lacks indication of zone/offset.
    "Mar 19 2018 - 14:39" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd uuuu - HH:mm" , Locale.US )
)                                      // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.toLocalTime()                         // Extract a time-of-day value.
.toString()                            // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 14:39

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input. Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms used in parsing this localized input string.

```
String input = "Mar 19 2018 - 14:39" ;
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms used in parsing this localized input string.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd uuuu - HH:mm" , locale ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because the input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f  );
```

Extract the time-of-day value, without a date and without a time zone, as that is the goal of the Question.

```
LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime();
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-03-19T14:39
>
> lt.toString(): 14:39

## ISO 8601

The format of your input is terrible. When serializing date-time values as text, always use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. You can see examples above in this Answer.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external library, the [Apache Common DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) provides many utility classes that you can use to work on dates. 
In order to parse your string to an object you can use for instance:

```
public static Date parseDate(String str, Locale locale, String... parsePatterns) throws ParseException
```

> Parses a string representing a date by trying a variety of different
>   parsers, using the default date format symbols for the given locale.
>
> The parse will try each parse pattern in turn. A parse is only deemed
>   successful if it parses the whole of the input string. If no parse
>   patterns match, a ParseException is thrown.
>
> The parser will be lenient toward the parsed date.
>
> Parameters:str - the date to parse, not nulllocale - the locale whose
>   date format symbols should be used. If null, the system locale is used
>   (as per parseDate(String, String...)).parsePatterns - the date format
>   patterns to use, see SimpleDateFormat, not nullReturns:the parsed
>   dateThrows:IllegalArgumentException - if the date string or pattern
>   array is nullParseException - if none of the date patterns were
>   suitable (or there were none)Since:3.2

Comment: This functionality is now built-in to Java 8 and later, in the *java.time* classes.